# Put Space between numbers in C#

Tags: c#

How I can write a program that inputs one number consisting of five digits from the user, separates the number into its individual digits, and prints the digits separated from one another by three spaces each. For example, if the user types in the number `42339`, the program should print

```
4 2 3 3 9
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
string num = "42339";
string result = String.Join("   ", num.Select(c=>c));
```

**EDIT:** 
This part is just for fun, I collected some alternatives from comments and also added a few

```
string numstr = "42339";

string result = String.Join("   ", numstr.Select(c => c));
string result = String.Join("   ", (IEnumerable<char>) numstr);
string result = String.Join("   ", numstr.AsEnumerable());
string result = String.Join("   ", numstr.ToArray());
string result = String.Join("   ", numstr.ToCharArray());

string result = String.Join("   ", numstr.Where((_) => true));
string result = String.Join("   ", numstr.Where(char.IsDigit));
string result = String.Join("   ", numstr.Select(char.ToLower));

string result = string.Join("   ", Regex.Split(numstr, "")).Trim();
string result = numstr.Aggregate("", (s, c) => s += c + "   ").Trim();

string result = Regex.Replace(numstr, ".", m => m.Value + "   ").Trim();
string result = Regex.Replace(numstr, ".", "$0   ").Trim();
string result = Regex.Replace(numstr, "[^.]{0}", "   ").Trim();
```

Comment: @AhmedIbrahim: if it's an `int[]` or `List<int>` you can use `String.Join("   ", ints);`, if it's a single int and you want to separate all digits use `42339.ToString()` and then EZI's code.

Comment: Or `string.Join("  ", numStr.ToCharArray())`

Comment: @YoryeNathan: or `numStr.AsEnumerable()`, you don't need to create a new array.

Comment: Excuse me ! right?  ` string  a;

            Console.WriteLine("Enter YOur DIG Number ");

            a = Console.ReadLine(); 
           
            String.Join(" ", a); `

Comment: @AhmedIbrahim: no, `String.Join(" ", a.AsEnumerable());` (or with `Select` as the answer shows).

Comment: With `String.Join(" ", a.AsEnumerable())` i don't get anything , when i write my DIGTS , i get " Press any  key , ! `use console `

Comment: @AhmedIbrahim:i understand, you don't know that strings are immutable. You have to assign the string which is returned from `String.Join`(or any other `String`-method) to your original string variable if you want to change it. So `a = String.Join("   ", a.AsEnumerable());`

Comment: `visual Studio 2013 `  and `console application`

Answer (score 2):

```
int number = 42339;
var str = string.Join("   ", (IEnumerable<char>)number.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are asking about the output on the comment prompt:
To make space between the numbers, use this:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(i + " ");
```

Hope it solves your problem

Answer (score -1):

```
int number = 42339;
string result = String.Join("   ", number.ToString().ToCharArray());
```